# How to find the base directory where vendor is installed from a composer package

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to find the base directory of my application from within a composer package.  Is there an composer API or proper way to accomplish this.

To clarify, if my package install looks like this and I've got files here (using psr-4):

```
/home/project/vendor/Acme/my-package/src/
```

how can I find /home/project dynamically?

Updated Info:

I'm trying to load a .env file from the root which contains an API URL endpoint via Dotenv package from within the package.

Comment: I wonder why you'd need the physical location of the project you are contained inside. This somehow states a dependency on the outside world, and probably should be handled by requiring the user of your package to provide that path instead of autodetecting it.

Comment: Updated question with more info.

Comment: Based in your input I'm seeing that you're suggesting I should just load the data on demand via constructor.. this is an easier solution

Comment: That's likely the better solution. If you want to reuse your code (if you don't, why do you put it into a composer package then?), the next project that uses it won't have .env files somewhere, but a completely different configuration system. Ask for the information you need to do your work: Strings, integer, floats, booleans from "the configuration" should be read from wherever and passed as a parameter either into a factory or the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
<?php

$root = null;

// Set the current directory.
// Make sure you set this up so
// that you get out of your own root.
// Assuming this php file is at the root
// of this composer package, this should suffice.
$directory = dirname(__FILE__);

// Go up until you find a composer.json file
// which should exist in the ancestors
// because its a composer package.
do {
    $directory = dirname($directory);
    $composer = $directory . '/composer.json';
    if(file_exists($composer)) $root = $directory;
} while(is_null($root) && $directory != '/');

// We either are at the root or we got lost.
// i.e. a composer.json was nowhere to be found.
if(!is_null($root))
{
    // Yay! we are at the root.
    // and $root contains the path.
    // Do whatever you seem fit!
    bootstrapOrSomething();
}
else
{
    // Oh no! Can we default to something?
    // Or just bail out?
    throw new Exception('Oops, did you require this package via composer?');
}
```

@sven There may be situations where this strategy might help. Like a general console app (phar) for any project and to avoid global installation but still load a bootsrap file. Composer allows bin files to be installed at the root https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md, but allowing users to place the phar file wherever they see fit is a plus.

One could argue about inversion of control, but imo, simplicity should come into play sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. I think I've figured it out..

Since I used `include_once './vendor/autoload.php';` in my index.php I can just use `getcwd()` from the package

Comment: No, you can't, because that value may be changed anytime during application execution.

Answer (score 0):

Based in input from @Sven best and cleanest solution was to collect input on class initialization and leave configuration out of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Try `saboohy/basepath` package. Gives directory of the project.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33119011)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$basePath = explode('/vendor', __FILE__)[0];
```